# F#: List and tuple How can i obtain the desired output?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I wanted to group the data such that it contains list where the first element is some distinct item(like key) and the second element should be a list of tuple where first element is a key.
For example: if the list with return type `(string * (string list * int)) list` is

```
[("key1",(["data1";"data2"],1));("key1",(["data3";"data4"],10))]
```

then the **output** should be returning 
**(string * (string list * int) list) list**

```
[("key1",[(["data1";"data2"],1);(["data3";"data4"],10)])]
```

```
let datat= [("a",(["a";"k"],5));("b",(["b";"z"],6));("a",(["a";"y"],7));("c",(["c";"k"],2))];;`
```

**The output should be**

```
[("a",[(["a";"k"],5);(["a";"y"],7)]);("b",[(["b";"z"],6)]);("c",[(["c";"k"],2)])]
```

**I tried:**
`datat |> List.map (fun (a,b) ->a,b );;`

*I could not obtain the desired output.I tried many times but i failed.Thank you for help in advance*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to group your items by the first item of your tuples.
So you will to do `datat |> List.groupBy fst`
This will give you the grouping you are expected.

```
  [("a", [("a", (["a"; "k"], 5)); ("a", (["a"; "y"], 7))]);
   ("b", [("b", (["b"; "z"], 6))]); ("c", [("c", (["c"; "k"], 2))])]
```

Then you want to clear the items from each grouped entry from their previous header. So you will map with a function taking only the second part of the tuple. `List.map (fun (groupKey, groupedItems) -> groupKey, groupedItems |> List.map snd)`

So the whole line is `datat |> List.groupBy fst |> List.map (fun (groupKey, groupedItems) -> groupKey, groupedItems |> List.map snd)`
And it will returns

```
  [("a", [(["a"; "k"], 5); (["a"; "y"], 7)]); ("b", [(["b"; "z"], 6)]);
   ("c", [(["c"; "k"], 2)])]
```